Show or movie featuring a humanoid alien who created a car out of a horse carriage
This show or movie featured a humanoid alien who created a car out of a horse carriage.
I recall vaguely a helmet resembling an old diving suit helmet.
Likely from the 70s or 80s, not set in modern times.

So car was from that time period too? Any other plot points?
